# Apache Alias - removes POST data?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, alias

I have an alias in my httpd.conf where I'm redirecting a single PHP file to another PHP file located in a different dir.

Though it appears as thought data POST'd to this file doesn't get carried along? Is that the case? If so is there a way to carry it?

I hope this is a nice simple one.

Comment: Do you use Redirect or mod_rewrite? First sends browser to another address and then you loose your POST data. Latter one should work fine. If it is just an Alias, then there should be no problems at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's going on; you mention an alias, and then you mention a redirect, but these are not the same thing.

The following says, when somebody accesses `http://myurl/image`, serve up the contents of `/www/image`.  *There is no redirect involved here*.  If a user submits POST data, it will be submitted to whatever path is specified.

```
Alias /image /www/image
```

On the other hand, `Redirect` (which, confusingly, also lives in `mod_alias`) will cause the user's browser to change to another page; using the same example as above:

```
Redirect /image http://myurl/www/image
```

So when your user accesses `http://myurl/image`, your server will send back a message saying, "This page has been moved to `http://myurl/www/image`", and your browser will resubmit the request to the new URL.

Keep in mind that you can have both an `Alias` and a `Redirect` clause on the same path, and the `Redirect` will take precedence--keep that in mind when looking over your rules.  If you really want to see what's going on, open up a terminal and try:

```
curl -I http://myurl.com/image
```

If you see `HTTP/1.1 301` (or `302`) or similar, you are being redirected, and the `Location` field will reveal the new location.  Hope this helps!